# MSSQL Having Clause, I don't know what is wrong with my query

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

I am new to MSSQL and I have collided with a wall here, what I am trying to do is to get the maximum value after summing and grouping up the value of the attribute "Quantity". After executing the query I have written below, I get this error "Incorrect syntax near ')'."

```
Select BookID, Sum(OrderMem.Quantity)
from OrderMem
Group By BookID
Having Sum(OrderMem.Quantity) = (select MAX(Quantity) 
                                 from (Select Sum(OrderMem.Quantity)
                                       from OrderMem
                                       group by BookID
                                      )
                                );
```

*The table involved is named [OrderMem]
Please help and thanks :)

Comment: Start formatting it properly so you can see how the brackets work ;)

Comment: Inside the 3rd `select`, you need to alias your column.  `select sum(OrderMem.Quantity) AS Quantity`

Comment: @avery_larry is right - that 2nd nested select needs an alias, or else in the 1st nested select `MAX(Quantity)` references a column that doesn't exist.

Comment: @TomTom I've already double triple checked the brackets as I am a very careless person but I think I didn't make such mistake here, much appreciated for you reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned in the comments, you forgot to alias `Sum(OrderMem.Quantity)` as `Quantity` in the inner most subquery.
But you can simplify your query by sorting the resuts descending and getting only the top row(s):

```
select top 1 with ties 
       BookID, Sum(OrderMem.Quantity) qty
from OrderMem
group by BookID
order by qty desc
```

Comment: Owh so the words "with ties" allow more than 1 maximum values to be shown? This is a new thing to me, thanks man greatly appreciated. Also the "As" statement can be ignored?

Comment: Exactly, for both your questions.

Comment: Opps, I am trying to accept 2 answers, is that possible? This is y first time asking a question in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

If you're at SQL server >= 2016 then you can use a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) to simplify things

```sql
DECLARE @OrderMem table (
    BookID int
    ,
    Quantity int
);

INSERT INTO @OrderMem
VALUES
    (1, 3),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 4),
    (2, 5),
    (3, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 1)

;WITH
    CTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT BookID, SUM(Quantity) Quantity
        FROM @OrderMem  OrderMem
        GROUP BY BookID
    )
SELECT TOP 1
    BookID, Quantity
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Quantity DESC
```

Alternatively, as somebody already mentioned, you'd need to alias a column and a result of a select.

```sql
select BookID, Sum(OrderMem.Quantity)
from OrderMem
Group By BookID
Having Sum(OrderMem.Quantity) in (select MAX(a.Quantity) 
                                 from (Select Sum(OrderMem.Quantity) Quantity
                                       from OrderMem
                                       group by BookID
                                      ) a
                                );
```

Comment: If by " SQL server >= 2016" you mean "SQL Server 2005", then yes, CTE is supported in versions of SQL server 2005 and newer.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks sir, the first solution you have suggested is a completely new thing to me, so I will need some time to digest it. As for the second solution, are you trying to create a temporary table for the second nested select? And you named it "a"?